# can malware operate on the login screen of windows 10?

Tags: passwords, malware, windows

Can malware record your keystrokes on the login screen of Windows 10?
Or only after the login screen?

I ask this because sometimes I enter my credential of another distro by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is it possible. It is possible to record input anywhere. For example with a kernel based keylogger, which are pretty common, even input from the login screen can be gathered.

Depending on the context of execution (user, run type...) the keylogger will have different rights, and may or may not trigger uac windows when first ran.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "sufficient access and rights"? How does this play with UIPI?